# XAMPP + Wordpress - doesn't start after update

Tags: mysql, wordpress, xampp

I've had problems with starting MySQL Database (XAMPP) after system update - OSX.

Finally, I installed XAMPP again. MySQL is working now, but after starting localhost/wordpress with page, WordPress is lunching instal page...

When I type title and e-mail, I have list of issues with databases:

```
[Table 'wp_users' already exists]

[Table 'wp_usermeta' already exists]

[Table 'wp_termmeta' already exists]

[Table 'wp_terms' already exists]

[Table 'wp_term_taxonomy' already exists]

[Table 'wp_term_relationships' already exists]

[Table 'wp_commentmeta' already exists]

[Table 'wp_comments' already exists]

[Table 'wp_links' already exists]

[Table 'wp_options' already exists]

[Table 'wp_postmeta' already exists]

[Table 'wp_posts' already exists]

About 200 issues: [Table 'wordpress.wp_options' doesn't exist in engine].
```

After that I've got "Success! Log in..." and Error 404.

I have files (wordpress) from my website and databases. phpMyAdmin works well.

Is there some method to open my website again on localhost? Or in the worst case to restore as much as possible?

Update:

When I click in phpMyAdmin on any database I have a "#1932 - Table wp_... doesn't exist on engine." Can I restore the content?

Comment: If you have a database backup that you can import (.sql file), I would recommend dropping the database and restoring it from the backup file. Check your mysql error logs, other databases could be corrupted too.

Comment: Thank you for advice. All my databases is corrupted...

Next time I will export backup and whole website by duplicator.

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer for you to accept, if you would like to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a database backup that you can import (.sql file), I would recommend dropping the database and restoring it from the backup file. Check your mysql error logs, other databases could be corrupted too.